why does this get DAGCircuitError?
When I run the simple circuit that just does multi-controlled rotation I had the error:
"DAGCircuitError: 'bit mapping invalid: expected 4, got 1'".

It seems the error occurs when a pass_manager.run is executed. Does anyone know how to solve the error?
thanks for your help in advance!
reproducer code :
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate, XGate, RZGate, RYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, SamplerV2 as Sampler
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit import ControlledGate
ry = RYGate(np.pi/2)
cry = ControlledGate(name="cry", num_qubits=4, params=ry.params, num_ctrl_qubits=3, definition=ry.definition, ctrl_state='000', base_gate=ry)

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.append(cry,[0,1,2,3])
qc.measure_all()

backend = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
shots = 1024
qc.draw()

isa_qc = pm.run(qc) # <-- error occurs here
sampler = Sampler(mode=backend)
result = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots).result()
pub_result = result[0]
counts = pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()
print(counts)

Informations:
qiskit 1.2.4, qiskit-ibm-runtime 0.33.2, python 3.11

Can you please file an issue on Qiskit github so that the maintainers can take a closer look? Thank you! https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/new?template=BUG_REPORT.yaml

It's filed, thanks!

I just saw it and there is already fix PR in place: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/pull/13475

I applied the PR locally then tested, but the issue still persists.

Really? Can you comment on the PR to let the maintainer know?

I'm using this workaround which uses RYGate(theta).control() instead of ControlledGate for now.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate, XGate, RZGate, RYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, SamplerV2 as Sampler
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit import ControlledGate

cry = RYGate(np.pi/2).control(3, ctrl_state='000')
qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.append(cry,[0,1,2,3])
qc.measure_all()

backend = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
shots = 1024
qc.draw()

isa_qc = pm.run(qc)
sampler = Sampler(mode=backend)
result = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots).result()
pub_result = result[0]
counts = pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()
print(counts)

result :
{'0000': 530, '1000': 494}
EDIT
In this entry, t-imamichi helped solve the error, "definition needs the same number of qubits as qubits argument". I had the stated error due to my misuse of ControlledGate.
Here's the corrected code :
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.circuit.library import ZGate, XGate, RZGate, RYGate
from qiskit.transpiler.preset_passmanagers import generate_preset_pass_manager
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Session, SamplerV2 as Sampler
import numpy as np
from qiskit.circuit import ControlledGate

ry = RYGate(np.pi/2)
circ = QuantumCircuit(4)
circ.append(ry, [3])
cry = ControlledGate(name="cry", num_qubits=4, params=ry.params, num_ctrl_qubits=3, definition=circ, ctrl_state='000', base_gate=ry)

qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
qc.append(cry,[0,1,2,3])
qc.measure_all()

backend = AerSimulator()
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
shots = 1024
qc.draw()

isa_qc = pm.run(qc)
sampler = Sampler(mode=backend)
result = sampler.run([isa_qc], shots=shots).result()
pub_result = result[0]
counts = pub_result.data.meas.get_counts()
print(counts)

Result : {'0000': 505, '1000': 519}
